# Difficult Formula can not figure it out

Tags: excel, formula

I have a very difficult Spreadsheet that I need to figure out a formula to get an answer. The Spreadsheet can have multiple rows (each row is a policy) In the rows there are several columns (A, B, C, D , E, F, G) Columns D, E, and F can have one of 4 answers (Right, Left, Up, or Down).

I want to create a formula that tells me how may policies (rows) have and answer of up or down in any one of the 3 Columns (D, E, or F). If it appears in multiple column I only want to count it once. Can anyone help with this formula?

I have been trying to use =SUMPRODUCT as The rows may be filtered by a column that has a name. Example: filtered on Paul (column A) to see a count of the number of policies that Paul worked on that have up or down in either of the three columns. I want to receive the total number of policies not the number of up or downs.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: To help you formulate a question so as to enable us to best help you, please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And then edit your question to provide the additional information required.

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/range-contains-one-of-many-values provides a simple method if you can add a column and reserve a couple cells for up/down

Answer (score 0):

If we can do it in multiple steps here's one approach

1. define range for Up, down
2. enter formula `=sumproduct(--RNG=D4:F5))>0` in H2 and fill down
3. enter formula `=Countif(H2:H6,"=True")` in bottom of H which denotes unique policies having up or down in cells D:F. (assuming each record is a unique policy)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work as I am importing a new report on a regular basis and all my formula's are hard coded at the top of the report. So I would not have column H to work with in this example. My top row of the report Is fields with the formula's and then starting with Row 3 I am pasting Data from a canned report coming from another system. So from row 3 down the data will constantly change, but the fields and the options stay they say. So I was looking for a formula that could get me this info in 1 step. i do thank you for the response however.